# Alignment issue in the "Similar Questions" side bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, sidebar, similar-questions

"Similar Questions" section in the right hand side bar is not aligned properly, the padding is missing. Since the "How to Ask", "How to Tag" and "How to Format" sections are having proper placeholder for the headings.

Sample screenshot:

> [image: side bar]

Also when the "How to Ask" and "Similar Questions" sections are displaying together, there is no space in between these sections.

> [image: side bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment issue in the similar questions section has been fixed recently.

Also "How to Ask" and "Similar Questions" sections are not displaying together.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Similar Questions]